# Htaccess rewrite that only effects a specific subdirectory and replaces specific end of url data

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite anything in my badges subdirectory that ends in f2 to rewrite to f1

http://mydomain.org.uk/identmood19/pluginfile.php/27/badges/badgeimage/7/f2?refresh=7595

http://mydomain.org.uk/identmood19/pluginfile.php/27/badges/badgeimage/7/f1?refresh=7595

I thought RewriteRule ^badgeimage/7/f2$ /badgeimage/7/f1 would work but it seems not

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.+/badges/badgeimage/\d+)/f2$ $1/f1 [QSA,L]
```